# 4-coloring the faces of a cube

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetry

How many ways to color the faces of a cube in 4 colors if methods that differ in self-alignment of the cube are considered equal(it means as i think that rotations and reflections  do not make any difference and we consider such motions as equal)?

I found quite the same problem, the solution was based on finding the symmetry group with 24 elements (rotations) and we could count the ways using Bernsides lemma (1/24*(4^6+6*4^3+3*4^4+8*4^2+6*4^3)) and we got 240. I was told to look through reflections (group of 48 elements). How do I have to count in this case? How will the finite formula look like? Help me, please

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Look into Polya's enumeration theorem.

Answer (score 2):

With this problem the key observation is that when combining rotations
and reflections of  the cube we actually get  all automorphisms. These
are given for the $d$-cube by labeling the vertices with $d$ bits from
zero to  $2^d-1$ and combining the  $2^d$ possible bit flips  with the
$d!$ possible bit permutations, for a total of $48$ automorphisms when
$d=3.$ Hence the  cycle index is easy to compute,  combining the flips
and permutations  to obtain  a vertex permutation,  apply that  to the
faces,  and factor  the result  into disjoint  cycles.  This  is shown
below.

```
with(combinat);

pet_autom2cycles :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs;
local marks, pos, cycs, cpos, clen, k;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1;

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs));
end;


pet_cycleind_cube_face :=
proc()
option remember;
local faces, verts, vidx, vert,
    flp, perm, subl, ind, cind;

    verts :=
    [[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [0,1,1],
     [1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,0], [1,1,1]];

    faces :=
    [{0,1,2,3}, {4,5,6,7},
     {0,1,4,5}, {2,3,6,7},
     {0,2,4,6}, {1,3,5,7}];

    cind := 0;

    for flp to 8 do
        perm := firstperm(3);

        while type(perm, list) do
            subl := [];

            for vidx to 8 do
                vert :=
                [seq((verts[flp][ind] +
                      verts[vidx][perm[ind]]) mod 2,
                    ind=1..3)];

                subl :=
                [op(subl), vidx-1 = 4*vert[1]+2*vert[2]+vert[3]];
            od;

            cind := cind +
            pet_autom2cycles(faces, subs(subl, faces));

            perm := nextperm(perm);
        od;
    od;

    cind/48;
end;
```

We get the following cycle index:

$$Z(F) =
1/48\,{a_{{1}}}^{6}+1/16\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}a_{{2}}
+3/16\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{2}+1/8\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{4}}
\\ +{\frac {7\,{a_{{2}}}^{3}}{48}}
+1/8\,a_{{2}}a_{{4}}+1/6\,{a_{{3}}}^{2}+1/6\,a_{{6}}.$$

We  then have  by Burnside  the following  formula for  the number  of
colorings using at most $N$ colors:

$$1/48\,{N}^{6}+1/16\,{N}^{5}+3/16\,{N}^{4}
+{\frac {13\,{N}^{3}}{48}}+{\frac {7\,{N}^{2}}{24}}+N/6.$$

This was computed from the cycle index as shown below:

```
cube_face_colorings :=
proc(N)
option remember;
local var, cind, subl;

    cind := pet_cycleind_cube_face();
    subl := [seq(var = N, var in indets(cind))];

    subs(subl, cind);
end;
```

We get the following sequence:

$$1, 10, 56, 220, 680, 1771, 4060, 8436, 
\\ 16215, 29260, 50116, 82160, \ldots$$

This  points  us  to [OEIS  A198833](https://oeis.org/A198833),  where
these data are  confirmed and we also find the  cycle index. The value
for $N=4$ (at most four colors) is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{ 220.}$$

**Remark.** We have for the number of colors being exact the closed
form

$$\frac{N!}{48} \left( {6\brace N} + 3{5\brace N} + 9 {4\brace N}
+ 13 {3\brace N} + 14 {2\brace N} + 8{1\brace N} \right).$$

This yields the finite sequence of exact colorings (six faces admit at
most six different colors):

$$1, 8, 29, 52, 45, 15.$$

This  points to  [OEIS A325009](https://oeis.org/A325009)  where these
data are once more confirmed. We get for exactly four colors

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{ 52.}$$

When  $N=6$  all  orbits  contain $48$  configurations  (distinct,  no
symmetries) and we get $6!/48 = 15.$